# Open SSIS package created from older Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

I have VS 2019 and I would like to open a SSIS package created from an older version of Visual Studio.  How do I do this without altering the functionality of the project in any way?
Should I go with the upgrade VS is prompting me to do?

[image]

Comment: You can try creating a new project and adding the DTSX from the legacy project to the new project.

Comment: is that better than upgrade wizard?  Why?

Comment: I don't know if it will work. It's just another option to try. It will also depend on how old your legacy package is.